# Setting and unsetting element style, with clicks

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to make some sort of **task list**.

I append list items by pressing the enter button and by filling in an input.

I now want to add a feature, by which, whenever I **click on a task**, it gets **marked with a line**,
and then with a **follow-up click** the **line gets removed**. This should be done **repeatedly**.

However, with my code, I can only do that once per list item. So, after I remove the line, I can't click on it and reapply the line style and then do it all over again.

I am guessing this block of code has to be outside, as a separate block of code.

```js
const things = document.querySelector('#things');
things.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    li.innerHTML = things.value;
    document.querySelector("#list").appendChild(li);
    // txtInput.value = "";
  }
  li.addEventListener("click", function() {
    li.setAttribute("style", "text-decoration: line-through");
    li.addEventListener("click", function() {
      li.setAttribute("style", "text-decoration: none");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <input id="things">
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

(using class(commented))

```js
const things = document.querySelector('#things');
things.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    li.innerHTML = things.value;
    document.querySelector("#list").appendChild(li);
    // txtInput.value = "";
  }
  li.addEventListener("click", function() {
    li.setAttribute("style", "text-decoration: line-through");
    li.addEventListener("click", function() {
      li.setAttribute("style", "text-decoration: none");
    });
  });

  /* li.addEventListener("click", function() {
      li.classList.add("lt");
      li.addEventListener("click", function() {
          li.classList.remove("lt");
      });
  }); */
});
```

```css
li.lt {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <input id="things">
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Toggle a class that has `text-decoration: line-through` in its CSS.

Comment: Just did. But same situation. After i remove the line, i cannot click and reapply it. It can only happen once.

Comment: You shouldn't add another event listener inside an event listener. You have multiple listeners that are undoing each other. I think you don't realize that adding a new listener doesn't remove the old one.

Comment: @Barmar i wasnt aware that by toggling you meant actually using a keyword toggle in my code. I am a begginer and still scatching and wondering through guides. Thanks also!

Comment: @Barmar I'll have that in mind while i  keep experimenting with it.

Comment: Even if you don';t use `toggle()` in the code, you can do it with an `if` statement like in Arky's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this html code:

```
li.addEventListener("click", function() {
        li.setAttribute("style","text-decoration: line-through");
        li.addEventListener("click", function() {
            li.setAttribute("style","text-decoration: none");
        });
    });
```

By this code

```
li.addEventListener("click", function() {
    li.classList.toggle('done');
    });
```

and in you CSS add a class

```
 .done{
     text-decoration:line-through;
   }
```

Comment: That's it actually. I am very begginer and i was tunnel visioned to the classList.add . Wasnt aware of the .toggle. I will accept your answer in 2 minutes when i will be allowed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Add a class in your css that toggles the line-through. In your javascript, toggle the class on click.

```js
const things=document.querySelector('#things');
things.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    if(event.keyCode === 13){
        li.innerHTML = things.value;
        document.querySelector("#list").appendChild(li);
        li.addEventListener("click", function() {
          if(li.classList.contains("line-through")){
            li.classList.remove("line-through")
          }
          else{
            li.classList.add("line-through")
          }
        });
    } 
});
```

```css
.line-through{
     text-decoration: line-through

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <input id="things"/>
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Update your js code to:

```
const things=document.querySelector('#things');
things.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");

    if(event.keyCode === 13){
        li.innerHTML = things.value;
        document.querySelector("#list").appendChild(li);
    } 
    
    li.addEventListener("click", function() {
    
      if(li.classList.contains('has-line'))  {
             li.setAttribute("style","text-decoration: none");
             li.classList.remove('has-line');
      }else {
             li.setAttribute("style","text-decoration: line-through");
             li.classList.add( 'has-line');
      }          
    });
});
```